# React Native firestore timestamp is null

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have ran into a weird problem. So I am using React Native in combination with Firebase. Up until recently I had no problem but today I have this bug where the Timestamps are becoming null.

Here is what it looks like in my Firebase console:

[image: Inside Firebase Console]

Here is what it looks like on the React.js web app connected to the same Firebase Firestore:

[image: Inside React Web App]

However when I do remote debugging on my **React Native app**, this is what gets logged out:

[image]

I don't really have any relevant code snippet to post because on both the web app and the React Native app I just get the data from the Firestore and then just add them in my Redux store. Nothing else fancy or special is done with it.

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue, using [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase). It was working fine, then I upgraded to version 5.2.2 and suddenly all timestamps are null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by downgrading my `Firebase/Core` and `Firebase/Firestore` dependencies from 5.16 to 5.15 (which is the version recommended by [React Native Firebase’s installation guide](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/ios) anyway).

Here are the steps that worked for me:

1. Assuming you're using CocoaPods, change your Podfile to:

   ```
   pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.15.0'
   pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '~> 5.15.0'
   ```

   (Also be sure to update the versions of any other `Firebase/*` pods.)
2. From your `ios/` folder, run `pod install`
3. Restart your project in XCode (or on the command line with `react-native run-ios`)

Comment: This is right. I had found the solution after researching online for a while but forgot to come back here to document it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you upgrade your firebase SDK recently? Firebase Firestore recently changed so that Firestore reads back Firebase Timestamp objects instead of system date objects.

From Firebase's SDK warning

```
/** So you will also
need to update code expecting a Date to instead expect a Timestamp. For example:*/

  // Old:
  const date = snapshot.get('created_at');
  // New:
  const timestamp = snapshot.get('created_at');
  const date = timestamp.toDate();
```